# github login and sync failure in updated vscode linux version

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

recently I installed a fresh version of the KDE neon user edition and I updated it and works fine.
I also installed the vscode Debian version and nothing is wrong.
but when I want to login with my GitHub account in vscode for configs sync it opens a firefox tab that I log in to my GitHub and authorizes the vscode and it succeeds and gets back to vscode and instead of signing in and syncing the configs it opens an empty unsaved file named something like this:

```
did-authenticate\?windowid\=1\&code\=6beea2fcb8a47e0ea49e\&state\=2efc5efd-9c68-4735-a4a0-fd690dd7aec0
```

in this path :  "~/vscode:/vscode.GitHub-authentication"
and after a few seconds canceled notification appears.
I've installed vscode for Debian version 1.63.2 which people in this [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/3102) had the same problem in version 1.62.2 and they are saying that this problem is fixed for them in version 1.62.3.
I don't have this problem with the Microsoft account sign-in.
what am I missing?

Update:
for testing, I tried to install an extension for vscode and I pasted the URL with vscode protocol in a web browser like this (vscode:extension/GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github), and instead of opening the vscode extensions tab, it goes back to vscode and opens an empty file in the same directory ("~/vscode:/vscode.GitHub-authentication").
so this is vscodes fault that cant handle the vscode: URLs.
I found out what the problem is but I don't know how to fix it
for the record I've updated the vscode today to the 1.64.1 version and still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BDtD.png)

First, you need to get the GitHub Pull Requests and Issues and GitHub extensions together. Then go to the section specified in the photo and give the details of the account and repository you are using. And then it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself and discovered that it's because the VS Code command-line application isn't designed to handle URLs, but local file paths. VS Code registers the vscode:// URL scheme with XDG using an appropriate `*.desktop` file and these URLs should be opened using the command-line program `xdg-open`. In Firefox, if you have not yet set a default application for vscode:// URLs, then it will ask you for a program to open it with, select `/usr/bin/xdg-open`. If you have already set it to a different default, you can change it as follows: go to the Menu -> Settings -> General -> Applications -> vscode -> Use other... -> Select `/usr/bin/xdg-open` as the program for vscode.

With the default for vscode:// URLs set to use `xdg-open`, then any future integration with VS Code should work naturally to open it as expected.